# How to delete Password Protected posts cookies when a user logged out from the site

Tags: plugins, security, password, cookies

I wanted to delete all the cookies set for password protected posts when user logged out from the site after going through those Password protected posts.

Is there any function to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The *post password* cookie is set with:

```
setcookie( 
    'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, 
     $hasher->HashPassword( wp_unslash( $_POST['post_password'] ) ), 
     $expire, 
     COOKIEPATH, 
     COOKIE_DOMAIN, 
     $secure 
);
```

in the `wp-login.php` file.

We can then use the `clear_auth_cookie` hook, in the `wp_clear_auth_cookie()` function, to clear it on logout:

```
/**
 * Clear the Post Password Cookie on logout.
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/198890/26350
 */
add_action( 'clear_auth_cookie', function()
{    
    setcookie(  
       'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, 
       '', 
       time() - YEAR_IN_SECONDS, 
       COOKIEPATH, 
       COOKIE_DOMAIN 
    );
});
```